# Django Rest API Metrics

Tags: django, api, rest, monitoring, metrics

I run an application in Django 1.10.5 which generates a REST API. I want to know and save all the GET requests either in log files or in the db. Currently, this takes place via Apache logs. Is there any other recommended app (e.g. Grafana) for this version of Django? I tried unsuccessfully to use drf-api-tracking..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Django 1.10 stopped being supported on December 2nd 2017, you should really upgrade to a supported version

Comment: updated already, thanks! Any comment about the log process?